# How to load local audio file using ionic2 media plugin?

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic2, media

I'm trying to load local audio file using media plugin on android platform.

`this.ringTone = this.media.create("assets/sounds/tone.mp3");` but  i got an error:`Error:{code:1}`

When i tried to load online file it worked!

Any one can explain how to load local file using media plugin.

> I don't need to use native audio plugin.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution,

You should put the android native path,

To became:

`this.ringTone = this.media.create("file:///android_asset/www/assets/sounds/true.mp3");`

And that work properly.

Thanks.